# xgboost building error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:

Tags: c++, gpu, xgboost

I'm trying to build xgboost with GPU support using the following [instructions](http://dmlc.ml/2016/12/14/GPU-accelerated-xgboost.html).

I have GCC 6 installed on my ubuntu 17.04 system.

But while the compiler tries to build the following module:

```
nccl/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/src/cuda_compile_1_generated_reduce_scatter.cu.o
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/6/tuple:605:4: error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
                bool>::type=true>
    ^
/usr/include/c++/6/tuple:605:4: note:         ‘_Elements’
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded my gcc to 4.9 version and it helped.